# Alert message keeps showing up despite deleting it

Tags: javascript

I have a script that is supposed to be run when the page is loaded.So the script didn't work at all.I tried  to delete everything add a simple  alert message to check if the `window.onload`event works or not.And its ok... Event has been called succesfuly.I  added my code again and executed it once more .And interestingly alert message pops up again and again despite deleting it I have searched  on similar threads but I coundn't a simimlar post.What should I do?

edit:

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
    var now = new Date()
    var res = "Time is here =>" + getHour(now.getHours()) + ":" + getMinute(now.getMinutes()) + ":" +
        getSecond(now.getSeconds());

    console.log(res);

    function getHour(inVal) {
        if (inVal > 9) {
            return inVal
        }
        return "0" + inVal;
    }



    function getMinute(inVal) {
        if (inVal > 9) {
            return inVal
        }
        return "0" + inVal;
    }



    function getSecond(inVal) {
        //later

    }


}
```

Comment: come up with code that you tried so far.

Comment: Maybe your browser has the page cached.

Comment: Don't forget to save the file after editing it.  (I've done this before)

Comment: @barmar  could you explain Its ok now

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/browser-cache-makeuseof-explains/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try to load the page deleting the cache? So many times the script is stored in the cache of the browser and the changes that you do are not applied.

Depending on the browser is how the cache is cleared. In chrome the terminal is opened and the button to reload the page is kept selected to access that option.